# IoT project with raspberry-pi3 and Bluemix. Error : TwilioRestClient has been removed from this version of the library

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, twilio, raspberry-pi3, iot

I'm doing a Internet of Thing(IoT) project, and I follow a sample from below sources. But I fail at last step when I push to start this app.
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/04/tutorial-using-a-raspberry-pi-python-iot-twilio-bluemix/

[1. I am using 'cf push to start the app', it works until crash.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB1yZ.png)
[2. I am using 'cf logs python-iot-hackathon2 --recent' to see logs, and there are two errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWD9U.png)

[3. There is a python code that given from tutorial source, i think i should edit the code from line7~12, but I do not know how. If there is another problem, please teach me how to do it. Thanks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3KzW.png)

ex. There are two error, if you can not see clearly.
1.
Err: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

2.
Err: Traceback (most recent call last):
Err: File "server.py". line12, in 
Err: twilioClient = TwilioRestClient(twilio Account, twilio Token)
ERR: File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/base/obsolete.py", line 20. in new_func
Err:   .format(func.**name**)
Err: twilio.base.obsolete.obsoleteException: 
TwilioRestClient has been removed from this version of the library. Please refer to current documentation for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For: 1. Err: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

You need to run this on the Raspberry PI:

sudo pip install twilio

If you don't have pip installed then run:

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

and then again: sudo pip install twilio

for 2. Err: Traceback (most recent call last): Err: File "server.py". line12

Basically the twilio client definition needs to be similar to:

from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

so from the trace, line 12 in server.py  should be similar to

from twilio.rest import Client //this should be also changed

twilioClient = Client(account_sid, auth_token) //this is line 12

Comment: After I install twilio, it has a error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sCUBeM/cryptography/ How to solve this problem? My python version is 2.7.9 now. And about defind account_sid, auth_token, should i put real code for both of them? Thanks

Comment: looks like you are missing some required packages

for this particular issue this would be enough

sudo pip install cryptography

You need to follow that recipe step by step. On step 33 it say that you need to install some requirements as below:

sudo pip install -r requirements.txt

The file can be found on this repo:

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/python-iot-raspberry-pi

Comment: Thanks. It works after I edit python code, like you said from line 7~12.